# How can I perform looped macro in C

Tags: c, macros

I have some macros defined such as

```
#define NUM_A 3
#define A1 10
#define A2 100
#define A3 8
```

The total count and the values are specific to the device.
Now I need an array looks like

```
int Array[NUM_A]={A1, A2, A3};
```

Now, if the total number, NUM_A changes to 4, and I have defined the macro A4, but I forget to append A4 to the array. The actual Array would be {A1, A2, A3, 0}. There won't be error when compiling. The error is also hard to be found when running the program. It's more likely to be happen when I write the macros in the header file and declare the array in a source file.
Can I write a looped macro to generate the array by the defined macros NUM_A, A1, A2 and A3? Or can I write an assert or something else to warn myself if the error occurs when compiling or running?

Comment: Boost has tools to do this. I imagine they are C compatible... I mean, they must be, right? Anyway, the long and short is that you have to write horrid macro magic... but it _is_ possible.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19117228/535275

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Boost is for C++, why "must" it be compatible with C? Any Boost code I've randomly looked at has always been heavily into templates.

Comment: What about simply omitting the number of elements in the declaration, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846920/define-array-in-c

Comment: @Codor that wouldn't help detect the case when the OP forgets to update the list of values to match the expected number of elements.

Comment: @unwind: Because the Boost.Preprocessor library works solely with the C++ preprocessor, which is identical to the C preprocessor. Thus, the tools that Boost provides to achieve the OP's goals should be compatible with the language he's using.

Answer (score 1):

Just a question/suggestion.

Do you really need "NUM_A" ? Atleast from the code snippet point of view, it is not required. Not sure if you are using it elsewhere for some other purpose.

You can declare the array as:

```
int Array[] = {A1, A2, A3}; /* So this becomes the only place to be modified, just add A4 in the future. No confusion with array size */
```

NUM_A is equivalent to "sizeof Array / sizeof Array[0]".

**Example:**

```
  int arr[] = {A1, A2, A3};
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]; i++)
  {
    printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
  }
```

Comment: +1, but even better would be `sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]`. That makes in more robust for type changes.

Comment: The problem have been solved by open array operators. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can assert that the array is of the expected size:

```
assert(sizeof(Array) == NUMA * sizeof(Array[0]));
```

That's a runtime check. There are various ways of doing it at compile-time depending on your compiler version; see [Static assert in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385515/static-assert-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to declaring your variable with open array operators as A.M.D. has shown:

```
  int arr[] = {A1, A2, A3};
```

You can also define a shorter representation of `sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0]`, by defining a macro to replace that statement anywhere in your code where `arr` is defined like this:

```
#define ARR_SIZE sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0]
```

The macro will evaluate to the number of array elements at run-time, ***And*** accommodates changes to number of elements in the array between run-times, with no need to edit the macro.

For `arr[] = {1,2,5,8,9,3};` ARR_SIZE will evaluate to 6
For `arr[] = {1,2,5,8,9,3,4,7,1,0,4};` ARR_SIZE will evaluate to 11

This is a useful code readability technique for things such as loops:

```
for(i=0;i< ARR_SIZE;i++); // is more readable

for(i=0;i< sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0];i++); // is less readable
```